# The PUT method is not supported for this route

Tags: laravel, forms, laravel-5

I cannot submit form information through to store function in laravel controller. The form needs to create a - new - profile for a registered user.

I have even recreated the project, and redone the form - moving back into plain html as I suspect that the `laravelCollective` functions may be causing it but still the same error.
I have even rearranged the the form attributes as suggested in another post/thread.

I have even recreated the project, and redone the form - moving back into plain html as I suspect that the `laravelCollective` functions may be causing it but still the same error.
I have even rearranged the the form attributes as suggested in another post/thread.

The Form:

```
< form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{ url('users/profile') }}" accept-charset="UTF-8" >
    @csrf
...
// input fields here
...
< /form >
```

The Routes:

```php
    Route::resource('users/profile', 'ProfileController');

    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

    Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
    Route::post('users/profile', 'ProfileController@store')->name('profile.store');
```

The ProfileController@store function:
//some code omitted

```php
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $this->validate($request, [
            'firstname'=>'required',
            'lastname'=>'required', 
            ...
            'desc'=>'required'
        ]);


        //handle file upload
        if($request->hasFile('cover_image')) {
            //Get file name with extension
            $fileNameWithExt = $request->file('cover_image')->getClientOriginalName();
            //Just file name

            $fileName = pathinfo($fileNameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);

            //Just Ext
            $ext = $request->file('cover_image')->getClientOriginalExtension();

            //FileName to Store
            $fileNameToStore = $fileName.'_'.time().'_'.$ext;
            //upload image 
            $path = $request->file('cover_image')->storeAs('public/users/'.auth()->user()->id.'cover_images/'.$request->input('firstname').'_'.$request->input('lastname').'_'.auth()->user()->id.'/',$fileNameToStore);


        } else {
            $fileNameToStore = 'noimage.jpg';
        }
        /*
        */

        $profile = new Profile;
        $profile->firstname = $request->input('firstname');
        $profile->lastname = $request->input('lastname');
        ...
        $profile->desc = $request->input('desc');
        $profile->save();
        return redirect('/users/profile');//->with('success','Profile Created');
    }
```

The famous error:

> Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \
>   MethodNotAllowedHttpException The PUT method is not supported for this
>   route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST.

Not sure what is causing the error, help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand it correctly this is for store function right? then you don't have to put `@method('PUT')` inside your form it should POST. The route of store in resource is POST.

this is your code that i deleted the `@method('PUT')`

```
< form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{ url('users/profile') }}" accept-charset="UTF-8" > 
@csrf ... 
// input fields here ... 
< /form >

The Routes: Route::resource('users/profile', 'ProfileController');

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::resource('users', 'UserController'); Route::post('users/profile', 'ProfileController@store')->name('profile.store');
```

and the PUT method is used for updating. When update in controller you need to pass id in your form that should look like this.

```
< form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{ url('users/profile', $data->id) }}" accept-charset="UTF-8" >
@method('PUT') 
@csrf ... 
// input fields here ... 
< /form >
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Still does not work. Even if I just try to dd() the content.

Answer (score 1):

you have problem in your routes file simply change your edit route to this route

```
Route::match(['put', 'patch'], 'the path you want /{id}','controllername@functionname');
```

you should notice that if you are new to laravel you should pass the id to this route as shown in this part **{id}** so that your edit function could display the previous data of it and also if you want to submit a the form it should have the put method and the html basic forms doesn't support that so you should find a way to submit it like using **laravel collective** or maybe put a **hidden method in your form** 
if it doesn't work please give me a call

Answer (score 0):

When using the Laravel resource method on a route, it makes things pretty specific in terms of what it is expecting.  If you take a look at the chart on the [manual,](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers#resource-controllers) it is looking for a uri with the updating element id returned as part of the uri.  The example looks like: `/photos/{photo}`.  I'm not sure that this is how you've structured your html form.

You said you were using the LaravelCollective to get this working.  This usually works fine, and has the massive advantage of easy form-model binding. But it helps to include the named route, which includes 'update' for the update resource.  For example:

```
{!! Form::model($yourModel, array('route' => array('yourRoute.update', 
                  $yourModel->id), 'method'=>'PUT', 'id'=>'Form'))!!}
```

I have not had an issue with the Collective using this method.